# how to test the functionality of SOCK_CLOEXEC/ O_CLOEXEC (close on execution)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, network-programming

I have an accepted file descriptor that set the SOCK_CLOEXEC. Can anyone tell me how to test the functionality of FD(accepted socket not any fd) that had set the O_CLOEXEC/SOCK_CLOEXEC

```
accepted_fd =   accept4(lsn_fd, (struct sockaddr *)& tcp_remote, &size,  SOCK_CLOEXEC);
```

please provide me by any method, any code of testing it, except by testing if FD_CLOEXE is returned by

```
fdf = fcntl(accept_fd, F_GETFD);
```

Code of Fork:

```
  pid_t childpid;
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid >= 0) /* fork succeeded */
      {
        if (childpid == 0) /* fork() returns 0 to the child process */
          {
            rc = recv_gd_flow2(0, accepted_fd, count+1); /* wrapper function calls recv() */
            CHECK_VALUE("recv_gd_flow, with 0", rc, 0, goto cleanup);

            execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL); //EXEC ls

            //CHILD
            if(accepted_fd != INVALID_SOCKET)
              printf("I am Child and sock is closed\n");
            else
              printf("I am Child and sock is opend\n");
          }
        else{

          if(accepted_fd != INVALID_SOCKET)
            printf("I am Parent and sock is closed\n");
          else
            printf("I am Parent and sock is opend\n");
          //

        }
      }
     // The purpose of this code to see if child has a privileged to get a leaked fd, i think he shouldn't
```

Comment: What is wrong with `fcntl` ?

Comment: it is only get if this socket set the flag or not I want to test the flag how it works with an accepted socket, I tried fork(), exec() but I didn't know how to test it with them or maybe i did something wrong .. please help :(

Comment: Do you think there is any method ??

Comment: Could you include the code you used for the `fork()` plus `exec()` test?

Comment: pid_t childpid;
        childpid = fork();
        if (childpid >= 0) /* fork succeeded */
          {
            if (childpid == 0) /* fork() returns 0 to the child process */
              {
                rc = recv_gd_flow2(0, sock, count+1);
                CHECK_VALUE("recv_gd_flow, with 0", rc, 0, goto cleanup);

                //CHILD
                if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
                  printf("I am Child and sock is closed\n");
                else
                  printf("I am Child and sock is opend\n");
              }

Comment: else{

              if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
                printf("I am Parent and sock is closed\n");
              else
                printf("I am Parent and sock is opend\n");
              //

            }
          }
        printf("b4 receiveeeeeeeeeeee \n");

Comment: @thuovila  can you suggest me what I have to do ??

Comment: @cnicutar do you have any suggestion ??

Comment: Please put the code in the question.

Comment: @thuovila check now I might do something ?

Comment: @thuovila any notice ?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your addition of `execl()`.

Comment: Note that you can't use fcntl to check for SOCK_CLOEXE, but you *can* use it to test for FD_CLOEXE afterwards (this gets set for a socket created with SOCK_CLOEXE) (I editted the question itself to reflect that-- assuming it gets approved by peer review).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

I notice you added a call to `execl()` in your code and test the socket descriptor *after* the execl. That will not work. From the [execl man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) :

```
RETURN VALUE
       The  exec() functions return only if an error has occurred.  The return
       value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.
```

On a successful execl the code after it will never execute. It is the execute process that must do the testing.

**/update**

It is called close-on-exec. You need to exec something in child process after `fork()`. Just forking is not enough to test this flag.

Here is an example (with minimal error handling and a few shortcuts):

accept4.c:

```
/*
  gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D _GNU_SOURCE accept4.c
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (void)
{
    int ld = -1;
    int ad = -1;
    int ret = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    int reuse = 1;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    pid_t w = 0;
    int status = 0;

    memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv.sin_port = htons(4567);

    ld = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ld < 0 )
        perror("socket");

    ret = bind(ld, (struct sockaddr *) &serv, sizeof(serv));
    if (ret < 0)
        perror("bind");

    ret = setsockopt(ld, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse));
    if (ret < 0)
        perror("setsockopt");  

    ret = listen(ld, 1);
    if (ret < 0)
        perror("listen");

    ad = accept4(ld, NULL, NULL,  SOCK_CLOEXEC);
    printf("Parent accepted fd %d\n", ad); fflush(stdout);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
        perror("fork");

    if (pid == 0) {

        char adbuf[2] = {0};
        char * params [3];

        adbuf[0] = ad + '0'; /* kluge for singe digit numbers */
        params[0] = "./child";
        params[1] = adbuf;
        params[2] = NULL;

        execv("./child", params);
        /* execv() does not return on success */
        perror("execv");
    }

    /* from man waitpid */
    do {
        w = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        if (w == -1) {
            perror("waitpid");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
            printf("continued\n");
        }
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

child.c:

```
/*
  gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 child.c -o child
 */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char msg[] = "Hello\n";
    ssize_t written = 0;
    int ad = -1;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Too few arguments to child\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ad = atoi(argv[1]); /* atoi() does not detect errors properly */
    printf("Child attempting to write to fd %d\n", ad); fflush(stdout);
    written = write(ad, msg, sizeof(msg));
    if (written != sizeof(msg)) {
        perror("write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(ad);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Usage:

1. Compile into a.out and child
2. execute ./a.out
3. telnet localhost 4567
4. observe
5. extra credit: change `accept4()`flags to 0 and redo 1-4

ps. I hope I did not do your homework/rob you of a learning experience.

Comment: what I have to notice ?? when execl() ??

Comment: you need to use exec() after fork() in one of your process.

Comment: Thank you now I understood its functionality, no I am just testing accept4, it is only extra credit to check SOCK_COLEXEC ... Thank you again :)